# Layout fails to adjust screen size in Qt

Tags: qt, layout

I am trying to make a GUI similar to the layout in Image attached.

[image]

The problem starts when I add the three frames besides the stacked widget.
Frame one contains some labels for status.
Frame two contains some buttons and two sliders.
Frame three contains a tab widget.
I am adding suitable layouts at every stage. The layout fails to adjust to screen size and the window goes outside the limited size. I tried setting maximum size for the frames and stacked widget but the problem stays. 
Can some one tell me if I am missing out on something.
Thank You

Comment: You may publish your code, then it will be simplier to identify the problem.

Comment: I am doing it through Designer. Placing widgets on group box or frame. Applying horizontal or vertical layouts to them and then applying grid layout to the box/frame. And at the end I merge them all in one common grid.

Comment: The designer saves the code to a `.ui` file that resembles `xml` that you could post and we could get a better idea of the problem for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should to understand, what is Layout is. And especially Layout stretching. Have you seen [it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html)?

Comment: yes I have seen it I and I have made a complex project using grids before. This ones a lot simpler and hence I am unable to understand why similar techniques of applying layouts are failing.